# Force a div class to use a different css class with jQuery despite duplicate names?

Tags: jquery, css, contains

I am trying to style a class different to others (with the same class name) based on whether it contains a certain text or not. I have managed to addClass, but the issue I am facing now is the master css class is overruling it. Code to show:

**HTML**

```
   <div id="master">
    <div>
        <div class="attributes">
            <a href="#">Not important</a>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div>
        <div class="attributes">
            <a href="#">Not important</a>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div>
        <div class="attributes">
            <a href="#">Important Text and Other Stuff</a>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div>
        <div class="attributes">
            <a href="#">Not important</a>
        </div>
    </div>
   </div>
```

**Original CSS**

```
#master div.attributes {
    float: left;
    font-size: 12px;
    margin-top: 0px !important;
    width: 330px;
    clear: both;
}

.attributes {
    color: #58585a !important;
    font-size: 14px;
    margin: -10px 0 0 !important;
}
```

**jQuery used**

```
$('div.attributes:contains("Important Text")').addClass('attributes2');
```

**CSS Added**

```
.attributes2 

{
    clear: none;
    float: right;
    font-size: 12px;
    margin-top: 0;
    width: 330px;
}
```

So it successfully added .attributes2 and uses it, however the #master div.attributes css class is overruling this. Can anyone think of a way around this? I have done countless google & stack searches, no luck... I should mention I do not have the ability to edit the HTML id & class names. But I can edit the css & jQuery.

So much thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to look at CSS [specificity](https://css-tricks.com/specifics-on-css-specificity/)

> Specificity is the means by which browsers decide which CSS property
>   values are the most relevant to an element and, therefore, will be
>   applied. Specificity is based on the matching rules which are composed
>   of different sorts of CSS selectors.

[Take a look here for more information](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/Specificity)

You have to add a more specific css selector.

Add the following css

```
#master div div.attributes2{
    clear: none;
    float: right;
    font-size: 12px;
    margin-top: 0;
    width: 330px;
}
```

> NOTE:
>
> When specificity is equal to any of the multiple declarations, the
>   last declaration found in the CSS is applied to the element.

Comment: Thank you, amazing! Yes, need to read up more on css now. Thanks a bunch again, this did it.

Answer (score 2):

This is happening because the id `#master` has a higher precedence than the class `.attributes2`, it has more [specificity](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Specificity). So, to fix this, you can just add more specificity to your `.attributes2` block:

```
#master div.attributes2 {
...
}
```

Please also note that you should do the same thing with your `.attributes` block instead of using the `!important` rule because the `!important` rule interrupts the cascading nature of CSS and creates harder to maintain code.